# How do I typecast final return value of a function which has implemeted function chaining in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, function, casting, return-type, chaining

I recently came across function chaining in Python, and I have this function which has implemented function chaining.

```
def add(n):
  class A(int):
    def __call__(self, n):
      return A(self + n)
  return A(n)
```

It works as:

```
>>> add(7)(6)
13
>>> add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
15
>>> type(add(7)(6))
<class '__main__.add.<locals>.A'>
```

Everything is fine, but I want this function to typecast the *final* return value as `int`.
Something like this.

```
>>> add(7)(6)
13
>>> add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
15
>>> type(add(7)(6)(3))
<class 'int'>
```

Is there any Pythonic way to do that?

Comment: What's the real problem? I can sense an XY problem here? why not just `x+y` and simply getting an int?

Comment: Through this I can also do `add(3)(4)(5)(6)` and get `18` as output.

Comment: Checkout the duplicate question.